# How to fill first N/A cell when apply rolling mean to a column -python

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-average

I need to apply rolling mean to a column as showing in pic1 s3, after i apply rolling mean and set windows = 5, i got correct answer , but left first 4 rows empty,as showing in pic2 sa3.

i want to fill the first 4 empty cells in pic2 sa3 with the mean of all data in pic1 s3 up to the current row,as showing in pic3 a3.

how can i do with with an easy function besides the rolling mean method.
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need parameter `min_periods=1` in [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

> min_periods : int, default None
>
> Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value (otherwise result is NA). For a window that is specified by an offset, this will default to 1.

```
df = df.rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean()
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(1256)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  5  8  8  9
1  3  6  3  0  6
2  7  0  1  5  1
3  6  6  5  0  4
4  4  9  4  6  1
5  7  7  5  8  3
6  0  7  2  8  2
7  4  8  3  5  5
8  8  2  0  9  2
9  4  7  1  5  1

df = df.rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean()
print (df)
          a         b     c         d         e
0  1.000000  5.000000  8.00  8.000000  9.000000
1  2.000000  5.500000  5.50  4.000000  7.500000
2  3.666667  3.666667  4.00  4.333333  5.333333
3  4.250000  4.250000  4.25  3.250000  5.000000
4  4.200000  5.200000  4.20  3.800000  4.200000
5  5.400000  5.600000  3.60  3.800000  3.000000
6  4.800000  5.800000  3.40  5.400000  2.200000
7  4.200000  7.400000  3.80  5.400000  3.000000
8  4.600000  6.600000  2.80  7.200000  2.600000
9  4.600000  6.200000  2.20  7.000000  2.600000
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add:

```
df['sa3'].fillna(df['s3'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

Hopefully I used correct column names.

Comment: thanks, but i may not describe my question clearly, however jezrael offer the answer i intend to ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to find the rolling mean and then fill the `NaN` with zero.

Use something like the following:

```
col = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
df = pd.DataFrame(col)

df['rm'] = df.rolling(5).mean().fillna(value =0, inplace=False)
print df

   0   rm
0  1  0.0
1  2  0.0
2  3  0.0
3  4  0.0
4  5  3.0
5  6  4.0
6  7  5.0
7  8  6.0
8  9  7.0
```

Comment: thanks, but i need more accurate numbers, but i have use 0 for those cannot be calculated, just not all of them,jazeral give the  answer i intend to ask

Answer (score 0):

I see, some of the answers are dealing with null and replacing them with mean and some answers are creating rolling mean but not replacing nulls with it. So i figured out the code myself and posting it here.

```
df['Col']= df['Col'].fillna(df['Col'].rolling(4,center=True,min_periods=1).mean())
```

`'4'` is the length of rolling window
`centre = True` indicates that the replaced value will will consider half the value above and half values below the null values to replace.